# How are agility scores calculated in Dying Light?

Tags: dying-light

In the original Dying Light for PC and Console, there are multiple activities that a player can perform which contribute to the character's agility score. Allowing the player to level up and gain new skills.

What are these activities, and how do they effect your score?

For example, utilizing parkour mechanics, such as ledge climbing and wall running will contribute to the score, but will merely jumping between buildings, or staying off of the street for a certain length of time.

Are there cumulative bonuses for performing consecutive actions, for example, will performing a certain number of ledge grabs in a set time frame give you a score multiplier?

Comment: You mean XP when you say score?